# Now -- how is this experiment turning out?

Tags: discussion

A more pointed version of my previous question. Besides a general slow-down, we are starting to get more questions regarding the poster personally getting a patent than questions about stoping bad software patents. As a generally pro-patent person, this is fine by me and I'm happy to be helpful. However, I do think there may be a larger lesson embodied in the site's body of posts.

As I said in the first version of this question: "Maybe the widespread feeling that there are tons of low hanging fruit of ridiculous patents out there is incorrect."

I think this site's total contents now represent evidence that might be newsworthy as a balance to the worst of the uninformed anti-patent hysteria in some parts of the press.

Answer (score 4):

I think that part of the problem is that there is not widespread knowledge among the user base of the realities and intricacies of the patent prosecution process. This is probably because there are likely not many patent professionals who take part here, but rather a bunch of really smart engineers who know enough about patent law to be dangerous.